# Laravel 5 adding conditional clauses query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel. I just want to assing the query to a variable and then append constraints as needed.

Here's the controller:

```
public function index (Request $request)
{
    $limit = 5;
    $query_params = $request->query();
    if(isset($query_params['limit'])){
        $limit = $query_params['limit'];
    }
    //This chained query works. 
    $query = DB::table('users')->where('id', '>', '23')->paginate($limit);

    //This one doesn't work
    /*$query = DB::table('users');
    $query->where('id', '>', '23');
    $query->paginate($limit);*/

    //also tried with @btl suggestion and with following code:
    /*$query = DB::table('users')->where('id', '>', '23');
    $query->paginate($limit);*/
    return $query;
}
```

It trows this error:

```
"message": "Object of class Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder could not be converted to string",
  "exception": "ErrorException",
  "file": "/home/sms/laraveresources/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php",
  "line": 399,
```

Any ideas how to achieve it?.

I didn't find examples about adding conditional clauses to a query on the official docs.

I finally got it working. I had to build and add conditions to the query in one variable, but paginate it in a separate one. Following code works.

```
   public function index (Request $request)
{
    $limit = 5;
    $query_params = $request->query();
    if(isset($query_params['limit'])){
        $limit = $query_params['limit'];
    }

    $query = DB::table('users');
    if(isset($query_params['sort'])){
        $sort = $query_params['sort'];
        $direction = 'ASC';
        if(isset($query_params['direction'])){
            $direction = $query_params['direction'];
        }
        $query->orderBy($sort, $direction);
    }
    $query2 = $query->paginate($limit);
    return $query2;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line of your code is giving you the error?

Comment: @sms show us your full controller, this is clearly not causing the problem.

Comment: @Sohel0415 Thanks for your time!. I updated the question with more information. Thanks again.

Comment: @btl's answer is right but you are missing to assign the last line query to `$query` variable. And always try to provide information as much as possible to help others to understand your problem, specifically your full error and in where it is causing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign `$query->where('id', '>', '23');` to a variable, as well. `where` returns the model instance with the clause, it's being lost by not getting assigned to a variable.

Try the following:

```
$query = DB::table('users');
$query = $query->where('id', '>', '23');
$query->paginate($limit);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!. It didn't work, I updated the question with more information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are `missing` to assign the query to a variable. Do this-

```
$query = DB::table('users');
$query = $query->where('id', '>', '23');
$query = $query->paginate($limit);

return $query;
```

Or -

```
$query = DB::table('users');
$query = $query->where('id', '>', '23');

return $query->paginate($limit);
```